# What and where is this class 'UniversalScalabilityLawForecast' in Micrometer library?

Tags: devops, monitoring, micrometer, spring-micrometer, sre

I'm reading 'SRE with Java Microservices'(O'reilly)

"USL forecasting is a form of “derived” Meter in Micrometer and can be enabled as
shown in Example 4-39. "

Example 4-39. Universal scalability law forecast configuration in Micrometer

```
UniversalScalabilityLawForecast
.builder(
registry
.find("http.server.requests")
.tag("uri", "/myendpoint")
.tag("status", s -> s.startsWith("2"))
)
.independentVariable(UniversalScalabilityLawForecast.Variable.THROUGHPUT)
// In this case, forecast to up to 1,000 requests/second (throughput)
.maximumForecast(1000)
.register(registry);
```

What and where is this class 'UniversalScalabilityLawForecast' in Micrometer library?? I can't find it
github repository, google searching, no luck.

help me please.

Comment: Ummm... Isn't it just defined in this example? (Just guessing.)

Comment: URL http://devguis.com/4-charting-and-alerting-sre-with-java-microservices.html

Comment: @CiaPan I thought so too. However, the text clearly describes it as a function that already exists. is it my misunderstanding?


"USL forecasting is a form of “derived” Meter in Micrometer and can be enabled as shown in Example 4-39. Micrometer will publish a set of Gauge meters forming a series of forecasts at various throughput/concurrency levels for each publishing interval. "